# MVC: Result from JSON Automatically fill View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am stuck in publishing the result from JSON so left the success portion blank.

View

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.About

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}


<p> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.test) </p>
<p> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.test1) </p>
```

Model

```
public class About
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
        public string test1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public JsonResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            About ab = new About()
                              {
                                  test = "a",
                                  test1 = "b"
                              };
            return Json(ab, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

JQuery in external file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var itemName = "#btn-about";

    $(itemName).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'Json',
            url: '/Home/About',
            success: function (data) {
                var option = '';

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOption, thorwnError) {
                console.log("Error")
            },
            processData: false,
            async: true
        });
    });
});
```

=> I am a bit confused now. Altough I get a result in JSON format using AJAX, I want to publish it in this View 'About'. The View already have @model defined, so as soon as I get the result, I want the view to load it automatically as I don't think its a good option to create html controls in Javascript.

=> Is it possible or do I have to fill control one by one.

=> I am new in to MVC, so could you let me know any good suggestion.

Comment: We typically don't refer to things as "control" in MVC. Instead we use the language of HTML/browser and call them DOM elements or by their specific tag name.  If you want to deliver more complex snippets - say a menu or tab - and still want to deliver it via AJAX think about returning partial views as HTML rather than JSON. With JSON it might be more difficult to update a complex HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your elements some id or class that will allow you to interact with them easily on the client. Then, when you get your response, take the values from the JSON data and update the elements (using the id/class to find it) with the new value.  I'm assuming you don't have any special template defined for your strings, adjust the selectors in the code as necessary to account for it if you do.

View

```
<p class="testDisplay"> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.test) </p>
<p class="test1Display"> @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.test1) </p>
```

Client code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var itemName = "#btn-about";

    $(itemName).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'Json',
            url: '/Home/About',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.testDisplay').html(data.test);
                $('.test1Display').html(data.test1);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOption, thorwnError) {
                console.log("Error")
            },
            processData: false,
            async: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well even though this does, but this isn't the solution I am expecting. From my point of view, in view we have '@model' and each DOM elements are link with it. So when I get the result from JSON, I want those DOM elements to populate automatically. Otherwise declaring '@model' on top of view is useless.

Comment: @LakpaSherpa - you are misunderstanding the view vs. the rendered HTML in the browser. On the server side, the model is used to generate HTML. The browser knows nothing about the Razor code on the server and, in the client, you have to interact directly with the HTML.

Comment: may be I am confused with MVC pattern. Thank you for rectifying me. I will look more details into it for getting an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var model = repo.GetModel();
    return PartialViewResult("about", model);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax("/Controller/About/", {
    type: "GET",
    success: function (view) {
        $("#aboutDiv").html(view);
    }
});
```

In Main View:

```
<div id="aboutDiv"><div>
```

Comment: Thank you. let me try this one too.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of returning the data you will have to return the view as string and the use jquery to replace the result.

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult About()
    {
        var model = // Your Model
        return Json((RenderRazorViewToString("ViewNameYouWantToReturn", model)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then using jquery you can replace the result in container for eg: div as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'Json',
        url: '/Home/About',
        success: function (result) {
             $("#divId").replaceWith(result);
        },
```

Comment: There's no reason to use JSON if you're going to return HTML. Just return the HTML and skip the JSON encoding.